# What exception to throw from overloaded operator

Tags: c#, exception, operator-overloading

I made a Matrix implementation which has an overloaded `operator *`. If there're 2 matricies of incompatible sizes I'd like to throw either `ArgumentException` or `InvalidOperationException`. Which one should I use? Or maybe it's move convenient to declare my own?

Comment: Sounds to me like InvalidOperationException sounds more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely create your own `MismatchingDimensionsException`.

Your users won't be confused by such an exception, they'll know what the problem is right away. It's the kind of problem that can happen a lot when dealing with matrices.

Now, do you derive it from ArgumentException or InvalidOperationException? I would say the former, but the latter makes just as much sense. If you use your own exception class, it matters less.

Comment: I would appreciate if you explain this decision so I can understand when to create my own in the future. Or point me to the documentation.

Comment: I added an explanation. There's no right or wrong here, it's just a hunch you get when you have enough experience.

Comment: This isn't an argument exception.  You provided the argument.  I would say it's an invalid operation exception as the user / UI developer didn't check the properties of the matrices prior to operating on them.  If it's the API call to handle the validation - then yes - throw an exception.  I would NOT create a custom exception for this.  I see projects that are overloaded with custom exceptions which becomes messy quick.  There is no reason why you can't use an invalid operation exception here with comment as to why it failed.

Comment: @tsells: The problem with using a pre-existing exception is that if one uses a `catch InvalidOperationException ex` to handle situations where one of the arrays passed to `ArrayOp` was the wrong size, such a "catch" block will also "handle" situations where `ArrayOp` calls some method which unexpectedly throws `InvalidOperationException` and `ArrayOp` doesn't catch it.  It's really too bad there's no notion of "expected" versus "unexpected" exceptions and catch sites, with "expected" exceptions that bubble up the call stack becoming "unexpected" exceptions.

Comment: @Supercat That is just it though. Exceptions should be unexpected.  If you expect to catch exceptions as you know they can / will occur, you should be coding for that so they do not.  If you can prevent it - then you should.  In some instances there is no way to do this (3rd party, .Net libraries, etc).  In this case though - you could.

Comment: @tsells: My philosophy about exceptions is that if a method has certain preconditions, and if a violation of those preconditions will cause a predictable exception "downstream", it should be better not to clutter the main-line code with tests for them, but instead deal with inner exceptions resulting from a violation.  Even if that triples the execution time of the "exception" case, it may be worth it if it shaves 1% off the time of the "normal" case.  Unfortunately, .net's exception-handling mechanisms have some limitations that make such an approach harder than it might otherwise be.

Comment: @supercat I wouldn't necessarily disagree with that either.  In my public API's (consumed be services, UI developers, etc) I do validate arguments and throw exceptions if they are incorrect.  This assists in keeping the API stable.  However if I am in the same project and have the ability to guard against this further up the stack I do.

Comment: I agree with this answer but I will add that I would personally suggest deriving from ArithmeticException when an arithmetic operator fails for some reason, makes more sense to me.